# $state.params and $stateParams passing data

Tags: angularjs, state

I've read many posts but none of them work: 
I want to pass some data using **$state.go**.

this is my state :

```
.state('app.404', {
    url: '404',
    views: {
      'header@': {
        templateUrl: 'views/empty.html'
      },
      'content@': {
        templateUrl: '404.html',
        controller: 'fofController'
      },
      'footer@': {
        templateUrl: 'views/empty.html'
      },
      params: {errorInfo: null}
    }
  })
```

this is how I pass the data :

```
$state.go('app.404', {errorInfo: {status: 403, message: 'unauthorised', fix: 'You have to login'}});
```

and this is how I try to catch the data in my controller:

```
.controller('fofController', ['$scope', '$state',
function ($scope, $state) {
  console.log($state.params);
}])
```

but the answer is an empty object (**{}**). I also used **$stateParams** like below but I get the same result, an empty object:

```
.controller('fofController', ['$scope', '$stateParams',
function ($scope, $stateParams) {
  console.log($stateParams);
}])
```

Comment: $state.params. errorInfo what does this give you

Comment: the answer is "undefined"

Comment: Your `params` config is inside your `views` config in your state configuration. Move it up a level.

Comment: @ JC Ford:  Oh my god... It's  been two hours I've been killing myself. Thank you so much. it was a silly mistake.

Answer (score 0):

option -1

```
.state('404.contact/', {
    url: '/contact/:obj',
    templateUrl: "contact.html",
    controller: "contactCtrl",
    params: {
        obj: null,
    }
})
.state('404.header', {
    url: '/header/:number',
    templateUrl: "header.html",
    controller: "headerCtrl",
    params: {
        obj: null
    }
```

})

option-2

```
$state.go(.....
```

You should try this code instead

```
$state.transitionTo(...
```

option-3

Perhaps try transferring with url

```
$stateProvider
.state('user', {
   url: '/user/:obj',
   templateUrl: 'templates/user.html',
   controller: 'UserCont'
})
```

Maybe these are the solution to the problem.

[Working example with $state.go()](http://plnkr.co/edit/qpk1GmbvaBDU01RYqtjj?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer but the problem was a silly mistake by myself. The params shouldn't be in the view section. As @JC Ford mentioned:     
Your params config is inside your views config in your state configuration. Move it up a level